# messing around with a simple game in html and js, values don't update properly

Tags: javascript, html

I am a novice web developer and was bored today so i put together a rough draft of a very strange clicker style game.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>HYPEBEAST SIMULATOR</title>
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>HYPEBEAST CLICKER</h1>
<button id="hypebutton" onclick = "clickButton()">HYPEEEE BUTTONNN</button> Amount of clout: <span id="clout">0</span>
<p><button id="buyjuice" onclick = "buyJuice()">Buy Vape Juice, cost is <span id="juicecost">10</span></button></p>


<script>
  var clout = 0;

  function clickButton() {
    clout = clout + 1;
    document.getElementById("clout").innerHTML = clout;
  }

  var juice = 0;




  function buyJuice() {
    var juicecost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(3.2, juice));
    if (clout >= juicecost) {
      document.getElementById("juicecost").innerHTML = juicecost;
      clout = clout - juicecost;
      juice = juice + 0.1;
      document.getElementById("clout").innerHTML = clout;
    }
  }    

  var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(3.2, juice));
        document.getElementById("juicecost").innerHTML = nextCost;

</script>
```

The problem is, when you click the Buy Juice button, it works and it takes away the cost from the clout cost, but it doesn't instantly update the values. It still says the cost is 10 after you clicked it, even though it changes to 11 but doesn't show it. The next time you click it, it changes to 11, even though the real cost is 12, so on and so forth. Any suggestions? I'm new to javascript for the most part so take it easy on me :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function buyJuice() {
   var juicecost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(3.2, juice));
   if (clout >= juicecost) {
     clout = clout - juicecost;
     juice = juice + 0.1;
     document.getElementById("juicecost").innerHTML = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(3.2, juice));
     document.getElementById("clout").innerHTML = clout;
   }
}
```

**Set text** in button after **recalculating juicecost**

```js
  var clout = 0;

  function clickButton() {
    clout = clout + 1;
    document.getElementById("clout").innerHTML = clout;
  }

  var juice = 0;
  function buyJuice() {
       var juicecost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(3.2, juice));
       if (clout >= juicecost) {
         clout = clout - juicecost;
         juice = juice + 0.1;
         document.getElementById("juicecost").innerHTML = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(3.2, juice));
         document.getElementById("clout").innerHTML = clout;
       }
  }    

  var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(3.2, juice));
  document.getElementById("juicecost").innerHTML = nextCost;
```

```html
        <h1>HYPEBEAST CLICKER</h1>
        <button id="hypebutton" onclick = "clickButton()">HYPEEEE BUTTONNN</button> 
        Amount of clout: <span id="clout">0</span>
        <p>
            <button id="buyjuice" onclick = "buyJuice()">Buy Vape Juice, cost is <span id="juicecost">10</span></button>
        </p>
```

Comment: this only works for the first 3 clicks. Math.floor is set to the power of 3.2, meaning when it hits 13, the cost is 14.

Comment: why do you have to calculate juicecost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(3.2, juice));  ? any specific reason?

Comment: its a game similar to cookie clicker, the more you buy upgrades, the more expensive they are.